# How to Resolve EndpointNotFound exception in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, configuration

I have been trying to resolve a problem that I am having with a WCF service hosted on our cloud platform. Service is written targeting .NET 4.0. I can access the service using both wsHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding over just plain http. However, when I try and access the service over a https end point it consistently gives me an endpoint not found exception which is odd because on the client I add a service reference pointing at the https end point and this should be sufficient to build a compatible proxy?

The web site has a SSL certificate setup which is valid, and the site hosting the service has a binding in IIS that uses this certificate. I can browse to the https URL from within the IIS snap-in and it finds the service with no problems, and I can use the same url from my desktop and get the normal "you have created a service page". IIS has anonymous authentication enabled only.

Here is where I get a bit hazy on what I have to do in terms of the WCF configuration.

1. In the server web.config I have security mode of Transport and
   client credentials of None (Think I need this because of the
   anonymous authentication on the host service)
2. Also in the server web.config I have set up mex end points for each
       of the server's end points that are defined.

Is there anything else I need to do here?

On the client side

1. I have created a basic console app, and create a service
   reference pointing at the https url and this is found
2. In the code I instantiate the proxy and call a method that invokes
   the service.
3. When I run the code I get the end point not found exception.

I have created a really basic ASP.NET web site on my local IIS that hosts a really simple service. I have added a self-signed certificate and in the mmc snap-in I have imported this as a trusted certificate. I have set up a wsHttp end point for both secure and non-secure and when I create a simple client that references the service I get the same problem when using a https end point.So I can replicate the problem I am seeing in the live environment.

The event viewer doesn't shed any light on anything untoward happening.On my various searches I found references to re-registering asp.net and the WCF runtime components. Tried all this to no avail. Getting really stuck. I've included the config from my local asp.net web site, and the client config so people can scan what I have. Any suggestions on what else I could try would be great. I'm hoping I have overlooked something obvious that another pair of eyes with more experience with WCF can spot.

Thanks in advance.

## Server config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="500" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service name="NorthwindServices.ProductService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NorthwindServices/ProductService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="NorthwindServices.IProducts">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Secure">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic">

            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings> 
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</

==================================================================================
Client config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
              <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IProducts">
                <security mode="Transport"></security>
              </binding>

            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost/Northwind.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IProducts" contract="ProductProxy.IProducts"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IProducts">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: in addition to the cloud endpoint ports, have you checked the Firewall settings of the VM in cloud? also do you have svc files to activate the services? or you have to activate in config.

Comment: and also the port 8732 of the base address in server does not match the one in client which is 443. And in IIS website binding, have you enabled https?

Comment: Firewall has port 443 enabled so this should be ok, and I have svc files defined.

Comment: If you could logoin to the VM, you may try connect from local, so you could further isolate the causes, besides, connecting from local may give your more debug info during browsing.

Comment: Good points. I'll have a look when I get a chance and see if this helps track the problem down. Thanks. Keith

Comment: I found an article on code project which solved the problem for me. I think the main problem was not setting the bindingConfiguration element for the service, and maybe also setting the clientCredentialType on the transport element in the client config to be None.

Answer (score 0):

BindingConfiguration is optional since an endpoint is primarily composed of address, binding and contract. If no wsHttpBinding is defined under bindings, the default configuration will be used; if there's one under wsHttpBinding without name or with empty name, the binding configuration will be used if the endpoint does not declare a named one. And you may have multiple named binding configuration under wsHttpBinding, and each endpoint may pick one accordingly. The problems so far according to your config files listed has nothing to do with bindingConfiguration as they all look fine. However, the baseAddress in service side and the client endpoint address do not seem to match, and I presume you are using svc files for service activation. Then you need to make sure the svc files are located in the right place through proper routing. Alternatively you may use config activation without using svc files.